# How to download image from JSON using the Swift 3 and Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, alamofire

How to download image from JSON using Alamofire and Swift 3? I am getting dictionary of data. See the following JSON response. I am able to print data in labels but I can't download the image. This is the response I am getting from the API.

> userJson userJson userJson userJson ["status": 1, "student": { "admission_date" = "14/06/2017";
>       "admission_no" = 13538; "class_teacher" = "Caroline Forbes"; dob =
>       "04/05/2001"; email = "ranisagar.sivadas@gmail.com"; "father_name" =
>       "SAGAR SIVADAS"; gender = Male; image =
>       "/system/images/86/j1f9DiJi_medium.jpg?1504593436"; "mother_name" = 
>       "RANI R S"; name = "Abhijith Sagar"; phone = 9066260799; religion = 
>       Hindu; "school_email" = "13538.861@demo.in"; "student_id" = 86; },
>       "message": Details fetched successfully.]

This is my code.

```
func SetUpUIProfiledata() {
    APIManager.sharedInstance.getParentDataFromURL(){(userJson)-> Void in
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(userJson)
        print("userJson userJson userJson userJson",userJson)
        print("swiftyJsonVar",swiftyJsonVar)
        let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()
        let sudent = swiftyJsonVar["student"].rawString()!
        let jsonData = sudent.data(using: .utf8)!
        let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        self.name_lbl.text = dictionary?["name"] as? String
        self.fatherName_lbl.text = dictionary?["father_name"] as? String
        self.motherName_lbl.text = dictionary?["mother_name"] as? String
        self.phone_lbl.text = dictionary?["phone"] as? String
        self.email_lbl.text = dictionary?["email"] as? String
        self.dob_lbl.text=dictionary?["dob"] as? String
        self.gender_lbl.text=dictionary?["gender"] as? String
        self.religion_lbl.text=dictionary?["religion"] as? String
        self.admissionDate_lbl.text=dictionary?["admission_date"] as? String
        self.admissionNum_lbl.text=dictionary?["admission_no"] as? String
        self.schoolMail_lbl.text=dictionary?["school_email"] as? String
        self.teacher_lbl.text=dictionary?["class_teacher"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in valid format

Comment: What have you tried for getting image from your response? And also check in image key whatever path you get its working in browser or not?

Comment: its working fine. @  Nishant Bhindi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at below code you just need to pass a link url to alamofire and you can download a image . if its not the expected answer please Re edit your question .

```
       let strURL1:String = "https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg"
Alamofire.request(strURL1).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
    debugPrint(response)

    debugPrint(response.result)

    if let image1 = response.result.value {
        let image = UIImage(data: image1)
         self.imageView.image = image

    }
})
```

I looked at output you had provided you are getting

```
 image =
"/system/images/86/j1f9DiJi_medium.jpg?1504593436";
```

is this a valid url or path if its a url you need to add your `base url + your " /system/images/86/j1f9DiJi_medium.jpg?1504593436"` and pass it to alamofire block to download image 
as in my above example

```
"https://www.planwallpaper.com" - baseURl
"static/images/9-credit-1.jpg" - image Path as in your case
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have image url and how to pass that image to url base url

Comment: you have base url and your image url is it ? just append them to a string and pass it in block let finalUrl = Str1 + str2 or FinalStr = str1 and FinalStr.append(str2) and use it

Comment: and my doubt is i am getting image from base url so how to take that image url and how to append to image url.

Comment: let FinalStr = baseUrl and FinalStr.append(imageUrlString) and then let strURL1:String = FinalStr and it is used in alamofire

Comment: let strURL1 = baseUrl + imageUrl and used in alamofire

Comment: can you tel me how to take image key from base url response. i am trying take image key from baseurl i am getting error.

Comment: i appended baseurl with imageurl but its not giving anything in output

Comment: self.imageView used here is actual UIImageView with outlet where are you passing result after handler is completed finishing its task'

Comment: Happy to Help :)

Comment: just before Alamofire.request make spinner start animating and here after this self.imageView.image = image stop animating

Answer (score 1):

First get the image key corresponding value & marge it with your base URL. Like

```
let url = "www.yourbaseurlhere.com" + "/system/images/86/j1f9DiJi_medium.jpg?1504593436"
```

Now create a destination path for it like

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(
     for: .documentDirectory,
     in: .userDomainMask
 )
```

Now use Alamofire download method like

```
Alamofire.download(url, to: destination)
     .downloadProgress { progress in
            print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
         }
         .responseData { response in
             if response.result.value != nil {
                   if let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as? URL {

                        let fileName = response.response?.suggestedFilename // get your file name here.
                        let finalPath = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName!) //get your file path here
                    }
              }
         }
```

Hope it helps.