# Loading image to Image Cell from URL

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm learning to code in swift.
I'm trying to load an image onto an image cell located within an image well.I'm using the following code

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var well: NSImageCell!
    @IBAction func clickme(_ sender: Any) {
    let image = NSImage(byReferencing:NSURL(string: "http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg")! as URL)
        well.image=image;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

No exception is thrown nor any image is loaded.
What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you allow Arbitrary Loads in App Transport Security settings?

Comment: @the4kman No.. hmm.. what is that ? :)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http).

Comment: @techno please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668160/asynchronous-downloading-of-images-for-uitableview-with-gcd

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168008/how-to-download-image-from-json-using-the-swift-3-and-alamofire/46168955#46168955

Comment: Which is your object of UIImageView?

Comment: @Jay This is a desktop application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this.**

Simple Way.

```
let url = NSURL(string:"your url")
        let imagedata = NSData.init(contentsOf: url! as URL)

        if imagedata != nil {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data:imagedata! as Data)
        }
```

Create extension.

```
   extension UIImageView{

        func setImageFromURl(ImageUrl: String){

            if let url = NSURL(string: ImageUrl) {
                if let imagedata = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imagedata as Data)
                }
            }
        }
    }

 //Use this extension

    imageView.setImageFromURl(ImageUrl: "your url")
```

Use AFNetworking.

```
//without placeholder
    imageView.setImageWith(URL.init(string: "your url")!)
//with placeholder
    imageView.setImageWith(URL.init(string: "your url")!, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Use SDWebImage.

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "your url"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```